# Analyzing Parallel Matching Algorithm - Why it takes O(n+m) time and work?

Tags: algorithms, distributed-systems, weighted-graphs, parallel-computing, matching

Using the algorithm provided by [this paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-642-40047-6_66.pdf), they said that:

> The algorithm defines a single phase of the local max algorithm. Each step of the phase takes at most O(log(m + n)) = O(logn) time and O(n + m) work in the CREW PRAM model. Over O(logm) phases, each with geometrically decreasing number of edges, the local max  es   time and O(n + m) work in the CREW PRAM model.

I understand that the number of phases is log m since each iteration of the local max algorithm removes at least half of the edges in expectation and I know that since we used a parallel algorithm the iteration will take log n. But what I didn't understand is why each phase takes O(log(**m + n**)) time and O(**n + m**) work, why it is specifically (**n + m**)? Could you please clarify to me why its (**n+m**) for both the work and time?

Comment: "they said that:...". Who are "they"? Your instructor? Your classmates? Another article? Where?

Comment: @JohnL. It's clear that I'm talking about the paper, so they I mean the authors of the paper

Comment: Where does $m+n$ come from? Your quotation is not a quotation from that paper as I had double checked. That paper says "Each step of the phase takes at most $O(|A|) = O(m)$ work and $O(\log |A|) = O(\log m) = O(\log n)$ time in the CREW PRAM model". Please update the question to use exact quote. Explain how *you* make $m+n$ appear.

Comment: "The algorithm defines a single phase of the local max algorithm. Each step of the phase takes at most $O(|A|) = O(m)$ work and $O(\log |A|) = O(\log m) = O(\log n)$ time in the CREW PRAM model. Over $O(\log m)$ phases, each with geometrically decreasing number of edges, the local max algorithm takes overall $O(\log^2n)$ time and $O(m)$ work in the CREW PRAM model."

Comment: I just noticed that the paper has 2 versions, one with m+n and one with m only ! See the paper here : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.4587.pdf